# How many executions can I perform per month under the free grant of Azure functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, cloud

I have developed a Azure function in Python and each execution costs this much resources :

[image: Graph]

As the Azure consumption plan provides a free grant of **4,00,000 GB-s / month**. **How many times can I execute this function** for free per month? How to do that calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The price is composed by three variables:

- Executions
- Execution Time (GB per second)
- Storage

Example:

If your functions will be executed 2,628,000 times and it takes .100ms to execute, then multiply again by the  * .125 (memory). This results 32,850 GB-s. However you won't pay as the first 400K GB-s are free.

PS:  you'll pay over the amount that will exceed 400k GB-s.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you please help me to calculate approximately how many times I will be able to execute the function for free based on the above data?

Comment: Does the grant apply to all functions altogether or does it only apply to each Function App separately?